# Is there a way to cache queries results on apollo client using variable values?

Tags: angular, caching, graphql, progressive-web-apps, apollo-client

Im creating a progressive Web App (PWA) that is calling a graphQl server and im using the the Apollo Client (Angular) to make the queries and mutations.
I have the following query:

```java
query GetAreas($connection: String!) {
    areas(connection: $connection) {
        id
        description: description
    }
}
```

my graphqlModule looks like the following:

```java
@NgModule({
    exports: [
        HttpClientModule,
        ApolloModule,
        HttpLinkModule
    ],
    providers: [{
        provide: APOLLO_OPTIONS,
        useFactory(httpLink: HttpLink) {
            const cache = new InMemoryCache();

            persistCache({
                cache,
                storage: window.localStorage,
            });

            return {
                link: httpLink.create({uri}),
                cache
            };
        },
        deps: [HttpLink]
    }]
})
export class GraphQLModule {
}
```

The areas returned will be different for different `connection` variable.
The problem is when trying to work with the apollo cache, this query caches the first value return, but when i do another query with a different `connection`, it goes fetch the previous cached query result for the other `connection` variable.

the apollo documentation only talks about caching for differents `__typename` and `_id` or `id`.

Is there a way to do this?  To cache different getAreas (with different `connection` variables)? Maybe with some kind of cacheRedirect?

Comment: That's already how Apollo works. Are you sure that the variable value is getting updated?

Comment: this will make me look dumb, but, @DanielRearden you are right, the connection was not updating correctly, seems like an error with the program itself. Issue resolved, thank you.